# Low-end DSP vs high-end MCU

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, dsp, component-selection

I'm currently working on a guitar DSP project, based on an STM32F407VGT6, but as I progress I come to conclusion that I'm gonna need a bigger unit (with SDRAM). The question that is ringing in my head is which is better, a low-end DSP, or high-end MCU.

For instance  let's compare STM32F439 in a 144 QFP package, with an ADSP-21489 in a 176 QFP.

Both units are around 100PLN (~€22/unit), and that is quite a lot of money compared to classic MCUs that are 1/10 of that price.

Why is an STM32F439? It is a 180 Mhz unit with DSP and FPU units in core, CortexM4F based, with an SDRAM controller. Currently it is the top unit on the MCU market, as far as I know there is nothing more powerful (the M7 is not on market yet).

On the other hand we have Analog Devices' low-end DSP, with 400 Mhz and all kind of DSP goods on silicon (I can't tell much about it as I've never used it).

The question is: which is better? The advantage of the STM32 are cheap tools, well-known core, good and free tools. Is a classic DSP much better, or is the difference negligible?

Comment: Or dsPIC, cheap parts, tools, and DSP features.

Comment: As for dsPIC I'm not really sure if it has sufficient power, it is 16bit unit, and it doesn't have SDRAM interface (I need it as I need to store samples from long period of time [up to 10s]).

Comment: 1. There's nothing wrong with using 16 bit parts for audio. 2. Storing samples for 10 seconds and a sample rate are things that need to be in your question.

Comment: As for 1, well it is, since nowadays 24bit ADC are becoming standard. As for second that is correct. But the question is about high end mcu vs dsp. I'd like to know if anyone has tested performance difference.

Comment: An AD DSP core is designed for DSP. The SHARC series makes its way into a lot of high end audio products. The Cortex M4 is a general purpose microcontroller. I highly doubt anyone has made that comparison because its apples-to-bananas.

Comment: Hmmm, I think You are correct, now it's down to curiosity how much better it is?

Comment: LPC4300 series is Cortex M4F at 204 MHz *plus* Cortex `M0` core. Might be worth a look.

Comment: If you're not doing DSP stuff, there is little reason to use a DSP.  Are you using multiply and accumulate?  FFT? Convolution?  Do you need a floating point processor?

Comment: As the first sentence states "Guitar DSP" so I DO need FPU and dsp instructions, as there is a lot of MACs and a lot of floating point operations. Also the general question was which is better.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to slightly extend your question:

## Low-end DSP vs High-end MCU vs Analog

and try to answer it.

---

### High-end MCU

Modern MCUs are very powerful. The table presented below lists the results obtained performing a synthetic test consisting of **two sequence of FFT and then by-element square and then dot product on a distinct 12800-point floating point array** within each iteration, expressed in iteration per second done [it/s] and iteration average time [us = microseconds]:

```
Device-under-test        it/s    time/it, us   Remark
TMS320C6422B             2.50        400 000
MityDSP-L138F            3.97        252 188   L3 cache off, about x7 with L3 cache on
InMys SOM-AM180X-L8      5.90        169 491   L3 cache off
VAR-SOM-OM3X            37.00         27 027
RaspberryPI             35.80         27 933
InMys SOM-AM180X-L8     52.20         19 157   L3 cache on
Renesas RZ/A1H          54.61         18 311   linux, data+code in internal sram
Colibri VF61            56.80         17 606
VAR-SOM-AM43           133.--          7 518
Sunplus SP7021         138.--          7 246   CPU@960MHz, DDR3@400MHz   
Allwinner T113-S3      145.--          6 896   CPU@1008MHz, DDR3@800MHz
BFK3.1 (Baikal-T1)     151.27          6 610
Intel Core i3 Gen1     949.42          1 053
Core-RK3588J         1 072.--            933
Intel Core i5 Gen1   1 583.84            631
```

As you can see, modern 500+ MHz Cortex-A5 w/FPU based MCU installed in Colibri VF61 beats a dedicated floating point DSP such as C642x based 250 MHz TMS320C. And does it significantly. But of course, Core i's beat them all.

---

### Low-end DSP

Being beaten by modern MCUs in performance, modern DSPs strike back beating MCUs in... **architecture**.  Generally saying, a DSP IC architecture is intended to continuous + on-line + strictly timed + isochronous data processing, i.e. it by-design has special units to regularly read-in and then process and then write-out continuously going digital data in a form of samples. Also, it can be integrated with ADCs as a original samples source and DACs as a processed samples destination, simpler and practically glue-less, again thank to dedicated "on-chip" architectural units providing dedicated interfaces. MCUs, even high-end ones, typically cannot boast in this.

---

### Analog filter

Both MCU and DSP are digital things. Working with digital, you need to understand its limitations: quantization and grids. Using integer numbers in filters is simple but gives significant quantization noise; using floating numbers in filters is flexible but gives implicit exceptions like a surprising NaN in continuous accumulation killing the filter off. Analog is alternative for that.

Maybe analog looks like something from the past, but it never looks like something useless, even today. Natural effects taking place in a lamp or semiconductor cannot be ideally modeled in MCU/DSP, maybe only in a supercomputer cluster but then not in a real time :-)

Making a choice between designing digital or analog, ask yourself what do you really and exactly want: **to control or to enjoy?** If to control, take digital, if to enjoy, be bolder with analog.

Comment: when you start putting analog circuits in the signal path of a guitar processor you might "enjoy" it but you're increasing cost, increasing design difficulty, and decreasing design flexibility for very little gain (unless you're selling to hipsters)

Comment: @crgrace Anyway you always put analog circuits at least an antialiasing filter before and a reconstructing (recovering) filter after the digital processing unit. Excepting certainly the cases when your processor uses a digital interface to the amplifier like HMRAI, HyperMAC, SuperMAC in Hi-End equipment. IMO, designing a good recovering filter tightly fitted with at least the digital filter implementing in the DSP is not so easy. Also as i understand the OP makes the device for himself, not for batch production.

Comment: Comparison should also mention unit cost and power consumption. You don't necessarily want a complete Intel PC in a guitar effect.

Comment: @filo PC as a guitar pedal... Why not? http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/how-do-i-use-my-computer-as-an-amp-and-effects-processor

Answer (score 1):

To come up with the ""best"" implementation of a given function, the first question is, can it be done with more than one method?  If the answer is yes, then the second question is, which method is cheaper, more reliable, easier to modify/upgrade, etc. and the "original question" will be answered automatically!